# Обработка ввода массива

Tags: c, массивы, ввод

Всем привет, мне нужно считать следующее данные

```
N: { 1, 2 }
W: { 3, 5 }
E: { 9, 1, 1, 1 }
S: { 1, 7 }
```

так, чтобы получилось 4 массива N,W,E и S в которых будут числа (они перечислены внутри фигурных скобок их количество не может быть больше 32). При этом нужно проверять наличие знаков препинания, после букв N,W,E,S долджно быть двоеточие, потом фигурные скобки, а в них уже числа через запятую. Как правильно обрабатывать такой ввод в СИ?

Я пробовал получать строки через gets, а потом уже обрабатывать их циклом, но таким способом очень тяжело контролировать наличие знаков препинания

Comment: Правильно - это так, чтобы работало. И других способов не существует - либо циклами, либо используя функции обработки строк из `<cstring>`, либо и тем и тем.

Comment: @DmitryK язык прогр. С, а не С++ какой cstring

Comment: Сорри, поспешил. Функциями из заголовочного файла `<string.h>`